# Google chrome not running in ubuntu 18.04 enviroment

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I'm trying to run the command `google-chrome` in ubuntu 18.04 lts using wsl, i get this error.
I have used these commands to install google chrome:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Error:

```
n-m-n@LAPTOP-OHGM6EBH:~$ google-chrome
[1111/122724.934073:ERROR:exception_handler_server.cc(361)] getsockopt: Invalid argument (22)
```

Comment: Are you able to run any GUI applications in WSL ?

Comment: @Marged I'm using xcfe4.

Comment: ... does it work in the same session you try to use Chrome ?